# how can you fix the error 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create this method where the user enters a DNA strand, then the method checks the user's input for the specific characters if it passes it print yes if it fails it prints no. When I Run the program I have the error below.

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

squence_str = raw_input("Enter either A DNA, Protein or RNA sequence:")

def DnaCheck():

    for char in ['A','C','T','G']:
        if any(char in squence_str.upper()):
            print "yes"

        else:
             print "no"

print "DNA ", DnaCheck()
```

Can anyone explain why I'm having this error thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want ALL the character input to be DNA sequence characters, I think you want something closer to this:

```
def DnaCheck():
    if all(c in squence_str for c in ['A','C','T','G']):
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"


print "DNA ", DnaCheck()
```

Assuming you really are looking for ANY of the characters to be a DNA character, you need to change how you loop over the sequence:

```
def DnaCheck():
    # this return true if squence_str is 'ABCDEFG' for example...
    if any(c in squence_str for c in ['A','C','T','G']):
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"
```

And either can be simplified to:

```
def DnaCheck():
    return 'yes' if all(c in squence_str for c in 'ACTG') else 'no'
```

Or if you just want `True` or `False` and (please pass the string to the function rather than use a global variable...):

```
def DnaCheck(squence_str):
    return all(c in squence_str for c in 'ACTG')
```

Or, better faster, take advantage of a `set` compressing any sequence of `'ACTG'` to be equal to or a subset of the same:

```
def DnaCheck(squence_str):
    return set(squence_str)<=set('ACTG') # equivalent but faster than all
```

(Uppercasing `squence_str` eliminated for brevity. With user input, you would want to add `squence_str.upper()` to the functions above...)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `any` here. You would if `char` was a string, and you wanted to check if the *any* of the characters in string were contained on the RHS. The parameter to `any`, `char in squence_str.upper()` evaluates to a boolean; not iterable!

Just use the `in` check to test for containment:

```
for char in ['A','C','T','G']:
    if char in squence_str.upper():
        print "yes"
    ...
```

However, to replicate your desired behaviour, you could do:

```
def DnaCheck():
    squence_str = set(squence_str.upper()) # use set for efficient membership check
    for char in ['A','C','T','G']:
        if char not in squence_str:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the any() function here is incorrect. The parameter passed to any() must be a list of some kind. The function will return true if any of of the elements in the list/set are True. Hence the reason for the error is you are passing a boolean value into the any() function instead of a list of boolean values.

Addressing the core issue, your approach is a mix of two. On one hand, you are iterating over the characters of the list, indicating you want to do one comparison in each iteration. On the other hand, you are doing all comparisons at once with the any() function.

I think this is more what you're looking for

```
squence_str = raw_input("Enter either A DNA, Protein or RN:")

def DnaCheck():
    for character in ['A','C','T','G']:
        if character in (squence_str.upper()):
            print "yes"
            break
    else:
        print "no"

print "DNA "
DnaCheck()
```